# Confirming whether in the special case of roots nature cubic equation can be easily solved

Tags: cubics

Suppose we are given that $a+b+c = A $, $ab+bc+ca = B$ , $abc = C$ , We can observe that if we solve by eliminating two variables out of three(a,b,c) from three equations we would end up getting $x^3 - Ax^2 +Bx -C =0$ a cubic equation which is satisfied by the last one not eliminated,

- So if we do the same with a cubic equation with two roots equal and going backwards we would have two variables and three equations so in general for a cubic equation whose roots we know are supposed to be having a double root can be easily solved as compared to the ones which are distinct in general ?
- So without cardano reduction stuff we can solve for all roots in this special equal roots case (double) easily ?

Comment: Are you assuming the coefficients of your cubic are integers? Or maybe rationals, which is reducible to being integers?

Comment: It can be for any polynomial x^3 +... Which has real coefficients i meant ? @coffeemath whose root nature we alrwady know from before

Comment: @Paracetamol The cubic has a double root iff $\,\gcd(P,P')\,$ has degree $\,\ge 1\,$, so in that case you have to solve an equation of degree at most $\,2\,$.

Comment: @dxiv yeah that i know i was not referring to that , i mean if i know already from start that the cubic has two roots equal , then if we are told to solve the cubic , will we need to use cardano to get reduce cubic etc .. or just solving the system of equations will lead the answer for both roots . Since we have three equations twl variables unlike the case of all three distinct where we get back to original equation while solving

Comment: @Paracetamol You don't have to solve the system. You can either calculate the $\,\gcd\,$ which involves just Euclidean division, or directly solve $\,P'(x)=0\,$ and verify which of the two roots is also a root of $\,P(x)\,$.

Comment: Oh yeah right , understood nice method thanks